# How to re-load page on redirect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I'm using React Router to add routes to my app. I'm redirecting to my home(feed) page from my AddAlbum class component using `withRouter` `history` once a user clicks save. My problem is my AddAlbum component is updating my home page so I need to re-load my home page once I redirect to see the changes made from my AddAlbum component. How would I accomplish this?

Here is what my routes look like in my App.js Component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/album/create" component={AddAlbum}/>
      <Route exact path="/feed" component={Feed}/>
      </Router>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Both AddAlbum and home(Feed) are class components.

In my AddAlbum component I'm using `withRouter` and `history` in an onClick method to redirect. Here's the full function with the button (Redirect on the last `.then()`:)

```
this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
this.save2 = this.save2.bind(this);

save2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let user_id;
  let image;
  let data;
  const { history } = this.props;

  Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
      user_id = this.context.user.sub;
      image = this.state.file;
      data = new FormData()
      data.append('file', this.state.file)
  }).then(()=> { 
      this.setState(prevState => ({
      files: prevState.files.map((file, index) => ({...file, index})
  )}));

  let files = this.state.files;
   this.setState(prevState => ({
   albums: {...prevState.albums, files, user_id}
}))

   Array.from(this.state.songsList).forEach(song => {
    data.append('songs', song)
  })

  data.append('albums', JSON.stringify(this.state.albums))


}).then(()=> {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/albums", data, { 
  }).then(res => { // then print response status
    console.log(res.statusText)
 })
})
.then(()=> {
  const { match, location, history } = this.props;
  history.push('/feed');
})
.catch((err)=> {console.log(err)});

}

onClick(event) {
  let albums = this.state.albums;
  if(albums.date  === "" || albums.title  === "" || albums.description === "") {
    alert("ERROR: Fields Must Be Filled In Before You Save");
    } else {
  this.save2(event);
  }
}

render() {
    return(
        <ButtonToggle onClick={this.onClick} color="success">
            Save
        </ButtonToggle> 
    )
}
```

How would I re-load my home(Feed) component once I redirect to it?

Comment: Are you using some sort of global state? because on every route change your component should render again. without any old values.

Comment: @JeanAguilar What do you mean by global state and where? If I click on links with React Router I don't think it's supposed to re-load. Idk about if I redirect using withRouter though.

Comment: The redirect works fine, right?

Comment: Yes, the redirect works fine

Comment: Please, add more code of the AddAlbum component. Specially the Save button section.

Comment: If your redirect works, your component will trigger a rerender with the updated state. If the state is not updated then you should probably change how you handle state changes

Comment: You might also want to consider wrapping your routes in a `<Switch>...</Switch>`

Comment: @ShawnYap so I should have something in my code that handles state changes like componentDidUpdate() or something? What should I have?

Comment: @NicoDiz Okay I added the Save function and button

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:** after your `axios.post` (9 lines before the `catch`), you do not update your state. That is why you do not see the changes.

**SOLUTION 1:** if the POST request returns correctly, update your state (adding the album to your album’s array).

**SOLUTION 2:** if the POST request returns correctly, reload your page with `window.location.reload()`, so you will get your albums updated from apicall. Something like this:

```
    axios.post(yourURL, yourData)
        .then(res => {
            // check if response is correct and
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch(console.error);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: my component gets the new data on the page if I add `componentDidUpdate` with the same setState as `componentDidMount()` in my home(Feed) component. The only issue is that I get a warning saying:
```Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.```

Comment: I asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661197/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component-when-adding-compone

Comment: This looks like a different problem: it seems like the albums are inside the Feed state, and Feed is unmounted. You can put that var on some parent state or, simpler, go with the solution number 2 and do `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick scan on your code but I think the problem is in your axios post request. This way, when you redirect to `/feed` it'll pull the updated data from that endpoint.

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/albums", data, {})
  .then(res => {
      // then print response status
      console.log(res.statusText);

      // redirect only when your http request is complete.
      history.push("/feed");
  });
```