# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when adding componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in the beginning my issue was that my component(Feed) was not updating my page with my new data(state) when redirecting from another page(AddAlbum). To fix that I had to add `componentDidUpdate()` to my component(Feed) setting the state in `componentDidUpdate()` to the data created by AddAlbum from my Node JS API. It does render my new data but I'm getting this error: 
`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Here's my code from Feed:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('COMPONENT HAS MOUNTED');
  let album = this.state.album;
  fetch(`http://localhost:8000/albums`)
    .then((response) =>
      response.json())
    .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ album : data });
     }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error " + error)
          })

  }

componentDidUpdate() {
   fetch(`http://localhost:8000/albums`)
    .then((response) =>
      response.json())
    .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ album : data });
     }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error " + error)
          })

}
```

Comment: You see how many problems with plain react set state, why not to use state manager?

Comment: My component isn't that big. Maybe I should here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use isMounted React pattern to avoid memory leaks here.

```
    constructor(props) {
super(props);

this._isMounted = false; }

componentDidMount() {
   this._isMounted = true;
   this._isMounted && fetch(`http://localhost:8000/albums`)
.then((response) =>
  response.json())
.then((data) => {
      this.setState({ album : data });
 }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error " + error)
      })
}

componentDidUpdate() {
this._isMounted && fetch(`http://localhost:8000/albums`)
.then((response) =>
  response.json())
.then((data) => {
      this.setState({ album : data });
 }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error " + error)
      })
```

}

and in your componentWillUnmount

```
    componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
     }
```

Read more about this [reactjs.org/blog/ismounted-antipattern.html](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to listen the warning and not try to update the state of an unmounted component.

- You can place that `album` var in the state of a parent component and receive the data as a prop in the `Feed` component.
- Another approach is to use a store manager (such as `redux`, `mobx` or `context`) and, again, place the `album` var in the `store` and receive it in `Feed` as a prop.

Comment: I think I saw someone do this. Why does this help my app?

Comment: Why does the first option help for this answer?

Comment: Inside your componentDidUpdate you make a fetch. By the time it resolves, maybe the Feed component is unmounted. Then you try to setState of album, that lives in the state of that component.
With the first (and also the second) approach, we make sure that album is in the state of a comp that is mounted.